# Verifying credentials without leaving view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got a user login page that I want to check if the inserted credentials are correct. Here's the controller:

**EDITED:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SustIMS.Models;

namespace SustIMS.Controllers
{
    public class MainController : Controller
    {
        public static string userName;
        public static string password;

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            getCredentials();
            if (Authenticate(userName, password))
            {
                return View();
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Could not authenticate");
            return Redirect("../Home");
        }


        public void getCredentials()
        {

            if (Request["username"] != null && Request["password"] != null)
            {

                userName = Request["username"].ToString();
                password = Request["password"].ToString();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is OK if the inserted credentials are correct: the `Authenticate` function verifies that and if it returns `true`, the `ActionResult` returns the `View`.

However, if they are not correct, I set it to return `null`, going to a blank page instead.

I want it to stay on the same page and display some kind of message to the user informing that the credentials aren't correct (by showing a `div`, calling a `javascript` function with a popup window, ..., I don't really know).

How can I do that?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here's my view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>@ViewBag.Message</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

</head>

<body>

    <div id="outer-limit">

        <div class="logo-main">
            <a href="../Home/Index">

                <img class="displayed" src="../../Images/logo.png" alt="SustIMS" /></a>
        </div>

        <section class="container">

            @Html.Partial("LoginForm")
            @Html.ValidationSummary()

        </section>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the partial `LoginForm`:

```
<div class="login">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Login</h1>
    <form method="get" action="../Main/Index">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" maxlength="30"></p>
    <p>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" maxlength="25"></p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" onclick="Refresh()" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you use AJAX instead? you will be doing async calls but you wouldn't be able to navigate to a different view unless you also send down the wire the url to navigate to and the client side would navigate to it.

Comment: It would be great but I practically never used `AJAX` - I wouldn't know how to. But I'll research a bit anyway, thanks

Comment: Very easy. tons of documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that :

```
public ActionResult Index(string url)
    { 
        getCredentials();

        if (Authenticate(userName, password))
        {
          return View(); 
        }
        else
        {
          TempData["ErrorMessage"]="Wrong Credential";
          return Redirect(url);
        } 
       }
    }
```

Then in your view Show the message in a div if it's not empty

```
@if(TempData["ErrorMessage"] != null)
{
  <div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable' >
  @TempData["ErrorMessage"] 
  </div>
}
```

Comment: This will actually return a view with the name "Wrong Credential", kind of, since errorMessage is actually not defined it won't compile.

Comment: Indeed, My mistake, this version Should Work to show a message in the view if the credential is false

Comment: @JDahm, this advances to the next view. It will just carry a string inside a `ViewBag` if the credentials are wrong. I don't want to go to the next view unless the credentials are right. If they are wrong, I want to either stay on the same view or reload it with some message in it

Comment: Ok, i thought you want to go to login/index View. If I understand well now, let's say you are on Home/Index, you go to Login/Index but if it's fail, you want to come back to Home/Index, with an Error Message? and If it succeed you go to login/Index

Comment: Then i've update my answer, Set your Error message in TempData, then Redirect to the URL you've pass to the action (the page who call login)

TempData still exist after a redirect, so you can get the message on the page.

Comment: Thanks @JDahm, I used a slightly tweaked version of your answer to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

doing something like this should work. Checking the ModelState can/will validate required fields via Attributes on your view (if you've implemented them) otherwise you can manually take care of that in your action. Adding the model error before returning the view will cause the error to display on the page after it reloads. Upon successful authentication, we're redirecting to another Action.

```
public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model) {
  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    if (AuthenticateUser(model)) {
      return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
    } else {
      ModelState.AddModelError("", "Could not authenticate"); //or better error
    }
  }

  return View(model);
}
```

be sure to also add an `@Html.ValidationSummary()` to your view to display the error message returned.

You should be able to tailor the above code to work with your methods, but ultimately, I would recommend strongly typing your views and passing a model back through a post.

**EDIT**
Redid my example based on your code above, rather than a general example

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    getCredentials();
    if (Authenticate(userName, password))
    {
        return View();
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Could not authenticate");
    return View();
}
```

My recommendation would be to `RedirectToAction` after successful authentication, rather than returning the same view.

Comment: I don't have any LoginModel, I compare the inserted credentials with data obtained through a webservice call

Comment: it should still work just the same, you may just have to modify it slightly to work for your "model"

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have any model. Or maybe I don't understand what you mean

Comment: You should simply be able to add the model error to ModelState add in my example and return the view after authenticating credentials. Even if you're not using a model. It was an example of how you could also do it

Comment: I've updated my answer w/ your code in the example, rather than a general example to follow

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've seen it. Now I teaked it a bit because it still advanced to the next view. I replaced `return View();` with `return Redirect("../Home");` and now it stays on the same page. I think I'm just missing the feedback for the user telling him the credentials aren't correct...

Comment: did you add the `@Html.ValidationSummary()` to your view? The message should appear there

Comment: Can you add to your question your view and controller code for review?

Comment: Is your action a POST? If you're submitting a form, it won't actually be calling the GET method again

Comment: can you also show your updated controller code? including decorated attributes

Comment: I've updated my question, now there's the controller

Comment: change your `return Redirect("../Home");` to `return View()` you're redirecting from the page, so the ModelState is refreshed on the new GET request

Comment: If I `return View()` the next page is shown. It's not working, I managed to do it using @JDahm's answer. Thanks for your trouble though!

Comment: I think you're trying to handle too much in your one action. Technically, it sounds like you have one Controller Action handling more than one responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have wrong idea how ASP.NET MVC works. If you submit form, the whole new request is made, and its response will be shown - that is, you must return something to display back yo user - typically view. Never return as `ActionResult`. In your case, you return `View()` in both cases, just give it different data to display - succeess message or error message for example. You can use strongle typed model for this, or `ViewBag` - take a look at some tutorials.

If you want user to "stay on the same page" if credentials are wrong, you need some kind of ajax validation. ASP.NET MVC supports this also, take a look at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(vs.98).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28vs.98%29.aspx)